# Issue with Angular localization module showing codes rather than non ascii characters

Tags: angularjs, localization

I am using [this module](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) to support localization.
When I use special characters, I see their corresponding ASCII code, e.g. `&amp;` rather than `&` or `&#224;` rather than `à`.

E.g. in my HTML I have `<p>{{"FooterA" | translate}}</p>`. In my localized json file I have `{"FooterA":"--- è ---"}` and the output is `--- &#232; ---`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in the sanitization: [reference](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1518)

As a temporary solution:

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
```

shall be replaced with

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);
```